# how to Download MySQL-Proxy in linux 16.04 (LTS)

Tags: mysql, linux, proxy, ubuntu-16.04, mysql-proxy

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I want to use Mysql-proxy.I want to download mysql-proxy by terminal with instruction and I have a ubuntu 16.04.

Any suggestions???

Comment: You should ask this on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). [Here](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-proxy/blob/mysql-proxy-0.8/INSTALL) are installation instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql-proxy project seems to be abandoned since over 2 years which is the likely reason for its removal from the Xenial repositories. It's probably incompatible with newer MySQL releases.

The 3-years-old INSTALL notice recommends version 5.1.x while the Xenial repositories include MySQL 5.7 and no older release.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, you can try below link also.

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/mysql-proxy